# Combinations: 2 different indistinguishable balls in k boxes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

We have $8$ white balls and $8$ red balls. Each white/red ball is not distinguishable from the other same colored ball.

Consider a line of $9$ boxes. If all the boxes are empty, we can describe it as this:

(_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _)

So, if we have $8$ indistinguishable white balls, that means that the following configuration of balls exists only once:

(white ball, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _)

That is, we have a white ball in the first box. It doesn't matter which white ball is in that box. It could be the first white ball, second white ball, third, 8th, etc etc etc. They all equal the same exact configuration in the above case.

So, given 8 indistinguishable white balls and 8 indistinguishable red balls, how many total configurations of balls exist given that each box can only hold one ball?

I've come across this sort of problem many times but since we have $k$ white or red balls where $k<$ the number of boxes, and also allowing empty boxes, I'm just lost.

The first time I looked at the problem I thought it would be as easy as $3^9$, $3$ choices for $9$ boxes (which isn't the case since we don't have $9$ red/white balls), but aside from that I don't know how else to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have is essentially right. There are $3^9$ choices if we ignore the fact that we only have eight balls of each colour available. But that restriction only affects two of these choices (all boxes having white balls and all boxes having red balls are the only two we can't actually get). So there are $3^9-2=19681$ options left.